# Android - Caching logic in Retrofit & OkHttp

Tags: android, caching, retrofit2, okhttp

This is what I am trying to implement:

[image]

If there is connection:

- Data was updated more than 1 hour ago: update data
- Data was updated less than 1 hour ago: get data from cache

If there is no connection:

- Data was updated more than 48 hours ago: show message "No internet
  connection"
- Data was updated less than 48 hours ago: get data from cache

This is my REST client module where I tried to implement before stated logic.

```
@Module
public class DarkSkyApiModule {

    public final String BASE_URL = "https://api.darksky.net";

    private static final Interceptor REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR = new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            if (NetworkUtil.isNetworkAvailable()) {
                int maxAge = 60 * 60; // read from cache for 1 hour
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                        .build();
            } else {
                int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 48; // tolerate 48-hours stale
                return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                        .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    };

    @Provides
    public OkHttpClient provideClient() {

        //setup cache
        File httpCacheDirectory = new File(FileManager.getCacheDir(), "responses");
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize);

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
                .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();

    }

    @Provides
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(String baseURL, OkHttpClient client) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .client(client)
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    public DarkSkyApiService provideApiService() {
        return provideRetrofit(BASE_URL, provideClient()).create(DarkSkyApiService.class);
    }

}
```

But result is not as expected:
If there is connection:

- Data was updated more than 1 hour ago:

> D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600 
>   W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :
>   /data/user/0/com.android.example/cache/responses/2fb62bf59f85c3371d74d511a3bbeac2.0
>   W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.android.example/cache/responses/2fb62bf59f85c3371d74d511a3bbeac2.1
>   D/OkHttp: [json_data]

- Data was updated less than 1 hour ago:

> D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600 
>   W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :
>   /data/user/0/com.android.example/cache/responses/2fb62bf59f85c3371d74d511a3bbeac2.0
>   W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.android.example/cache/responses/2fb62bf59f85c3371d74d511a3bbeac2.1
>   D/OkHttp: [json_data]

If there is no connection:

- Data was updated more than 1 hour ago:

> Unable to resolve host "api.darksky.net": No address associated with
>   hostname

- Data was updated less than 48 hours ago:

  > W/System.err: remove failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/com.android.example/cache/responses/journal.tmp
  >   D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600 
  >   D/OkHttp: [json_data]

FileManager.java

```
public class FileManager {

    static Context context;

    public static void init(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }

    public static File getCacheDir(){
        return context.getCacheDir();
    }

}
```

How to solve this problem? What I should set as max-age and max-stale?

Comment: Are you manually accessing the contents of the cache directory? Deleting them, perhaps? That's the only way I can imagine the ENOENT error, and I think that's going to cause you grief.

Comment: Or maybe you just need to make your OkHttpClient a singleton?

Comment: @JesseWilson, I am accessing the directory using context.getCacheDir(). I have added my FileManager class to show how I am accessing cache directory. This is the only point where I am accessing cache directory. I am also wondering why I am getting this error. Should it not be created automatically? I mean cache file.

Comment: @JesseWilson, tried to make OkHttpClient singleton, unfortunately not helping

Comment: As a singleton do you get the same errors? Or different ones?